# Cannot stream with Live555 server - Example not working

Tags: c++, streaming, live555

Recently I downloaded Live555 server source code from their site. I tried to compile and run `testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer.cpp` file in the `testProgs` directory. I compiled the whole project including the test programs successfully. Then I run the `testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer` test program. I also placed a `test.mpg` file in the current directory as defined in the test program. After running I got the following output:

```
Play this stream using the URL "rtsp://192.168.2.22:5555/testStream"
Beginning streaming...
Beginning to read from file...
...done reading from file
Beginning to read from file...
...done reading from file
etc.,
```

Then I copy and play the URL `rtsp://192.168.2.22:5555/testStream` using VLC media player, but VLC just wait sometime and then stop (same with Gnome MPlayer also). It does not play any audio or video. Any help is appreciated as I cannot go forward without successfully streaming using Live555. Here is the code of `testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer.cpp`. Can you tell me what am I missing...

```
/**********
This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the
Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your
option) any later version. (See <http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html>.)

This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License for
more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA
**********/
// Copyright (c) 1996-2010, Live Networks, Inc.  All rights reserved
// A test program that reads a MPEG-1 or 2 Program Stream file,
// splits it into Audio and Video Elementary Streams,
// and streams both using RTP
// main program

#include "liveMedia.hh"
#include "BasicUsageEnvironment.hh"
#include "GroupsockHelper.hh"

UsageEnvironment* env;
char const* inputFileName = "test.mpg";
MPEG1or2Demux* mpegDemux;
FramedSource* audioSource;
FramedSource* videoSource;
RTPSink* audioSink;
RTPSink* videoSink;

void play(); // forward

// To stream using "source-specific multicast" (SSM), uncomment the following:
//#define USE_SSM 1
#ifdef USE_SSM
Boolean const isSSM = True;
#else
Boolean const isSSM = False;
#endif

// To set up an internal RTSP server, uncomment the following:
#define IMPLEMENT_RTSP_SERVER 1
// (Note that this RTSP server works for multicast only)

// To stream *only* MPEG "I" frames (e.g., to reduce network bandwidth),
// change the following "False" to "True":
Boolean iFramesOnly = False;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Begin by setting up our usage environment:
  TaskScheduler* scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
  env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

  // Create 'groupsocks' for RTP and RTCP:
  char const* destinationAddressStr
#ifdef USE_SSM
    = "192.168.1.255";
#else
    = "192.168.1.255";
  // Note: This is a multicast address.  If you wish to stream using
  // unicast instead, then replace this string with the unicast address
  // of the (single) destination.  (You may also need to make a similar
  // change to the receiver program.)
#endif
  const unsigned short rtpPortNumAudio = 6666;
  const unsigned short rtcpPortNumAudio = rtpPortNumAudio+1;
  const unsigned short rtpPortNumVideo = 8888;
  const unsigned short rtcpPortNumVideo = rtpPortNumVideo+1;
  const unsigned char ttl = 7; // low, in case routers don't admin scope

  struct in_addr destinationAddress;
  destinationAddress.s_addr = our_inet_addr(destinationAddressStr);
  const Port rtpPortAudio(rtpPortNumAudio);
  const Port rtcpPortAudio(rtcpPortNumAudio);
  const Port rtpPortVideo(rtpPortNumVideo);
  const Port rtcpPortVideo(rtcpPortNumVideo);

  Groupsock rtpGroupsockAudio(*env, destinationAddress, rtpPortAudio, ttl);
  Groupsock rtcpGroupsockAudio(*env, destinationAddress, rtcpPortAudio, ttl);
  Groupsock rtpGroupsockVideo(*env, destinationAddress, rtpPortVideo, ttl);
  Groupsock rtcpGroupsockVideo(*env, destinationAddress, rtcpPortVideo, ttl);
#ifdef USE_SSM
  rtpGroupsockAudio.multicastSendOnly();
  rtcpGroupsockAudio.multicastSendOnly();
  rtpGroupsockVideo.multicastSendOnly();
  rtcpGroupsockVideo.multicastSendOnly();
#endif

  // Create a 'MPEG Audio RTP' sink from the RTP 'groupsock':
  audioSink = MPEG1or2AudioRTPSink::createNew(*env, &rtpGroupsockAudio);

  // Create (and start) a 'RTCP instance' for this RTP sink:
  const unsigned estimatedSessionBandwidthAudio = 160; // in kbps; for RTCP b/w share
  const unsigned maxCNAMElen = 100;
  unsigned char CNAME[maxCNAMElen+1];
  gethostname((char*)CNAME, maxCNAMElen);
  CNAME[maxCNAMElen] = '\0'; // just in case
#ifdef IMPLEMENT_RTSP_SERVER
  RTCPInstance* audioRTCP =
#endif
    RTCPInstance::createNew(*env, &rtcpGroupsockAudio,
                estimatedSessionBandwidthAudio, CNAME,
                audioSink, NULL /* we're a server */, isSSM);
  // Note: This starts RTCP running automatically

  // Create a 'MPEG Video RTP' sink from the RTP 'groupsock':
  videoSink = MPEG1or2VideoRTPSink::createNew(*env, &rtpGroupsockVideo);

  // Create (and start) a 'RTCP instance' for this RTP sink:
  const unsigned estimatedSessionBandwidthVideo = 4500; // in kbps; for RTCP b/w share
#ifdef IMPLEMENT_RTSP_SERVER
  RTCPInstance* videoRTCP =
#endif
    RTCPInstance::createNew(*env, &rtcpGroupsockVideo,
                  estimatedSessionBandwidthVideo, CNAME,
                  videoSink, NULL /* we're a server */, isSSM);
  // Note: This starts RTCP running automatically

#ifdef IMPLEMENT_RTSP_SERVER
  RTSPServer* rtspServer = RTSPServer::createNew(*env, 5555);
  // Note that this (attempts to) start a server on the default RTSP server
  // port: 554.  To use a different port number, add it as an extra
  // (optional) parameter to the "RTSPServer::createNew()" call above.
  if (rtspServer == NULL) {
    *env << "Failed to create RTSP server: " << env->getResultMsg() << "\n";
    exit(1);
  }
  ServerMediaSession* sms
    = ServerMediaSession::createNew(*env, "testStream", inputFileName,
           "Session streamed by \"testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer\"",
                       isSSM);
  sms->addSubsession(PassiveServerMediaSubsession::createNew(*audioSink, audioRTCP));
  sms->addSubsession(PassiveServerMediaSubsession::createNew(*videoSink, videoRTCP));
  rtspServer->addServerMediaSession(sms);

  char* url = rtspServer->rtspURL(sms);
  *env << "Play this stream using the URL \"" << url << "\"\n";
  delete[] url;
#endif

  // Finally, start the streaming:
  *env << "Beginning streaming...\n";
  play();

  env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop(); // does not return

  return 0; // only to prevent compiler warning
}

void afterPlaying(void* clientData) {
  // One of the sinks has ended playing.
  // Check whether any of the sources have a pending read.  If so,
  // wait until its sink ends playing also:
  if (audioSource->isCurrentlyAwaitingData()
      || videoSource->isCurrentlyAwaitingData()) return;

  // Now that both sinks have ended, close both input sources,
  // and start playing again:
  *env << "...done reading from file\n";

  audioSink->stopPlaying();
  videoSink->stopPlaying();
      // ensures that both are shut down
  Medium::close(audioSource);
  Medium::close(videoSource);
  Medium::close(mpegDemux);
  // Note: This also closes the input file that this source read from.

  // Start playing once again:
  play();
}

void play() {
  // Open the input file as a 'byte-stream file source':
  ByteStreamFileSource* fileSource
    = ByteStreamFileSource::createNew(*env, inputFileName);
  if (fileSource == NULL) {
    *env << "Unable to open file \"" << inputFileName
     << "\" as a byte-stream file source\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  // We must demultiplex Audio and Video Elementary Streams
  // from the input source:
  mpegDemux = MPEG1or2Demux::createNew(*env, fileSource);
  FramedSource* audioES = mpegDemux->newAudioStream();
  FramedSource* videoES = mpegDemux->newVideoStream();

  // Create a framer for each Elementary Stream:
  audioSource
    = MPEG1or2AudioStreamFramer::createNew(*env, audioES);
  videoSource
    = MPEG1or2VideoStreamFramer::createNew(*env, videoES, iFramesOnly);

  // Finally, start playing each sink.
  *env << "Beginning to read from file...\n";
  videoSink->startPlaying(*videoSource, afterPlaying, videoSink);
  audioSink->startPlaying(*audioSource, afterPlaying, audioSink);
}
```

**EDIT 1:** `openRTSP` output

```
[jomit@jomoos live2]$ testProgs/openRTSP -o rtsp://192.168.2.22:5555/testStream
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.2.22:5555/testStream RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: testProgs/openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.03.08)


Received OPTIONS response: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 08:30:23 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, SET_PARAMETER


RTSP "OPTIONS" request returned: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE,     SET_PARAMETER
```

**EDIT 2:** port check

I used Zenmap to scan the ports, and it shows 5555 as a tcp port and as open. But it shows the application as freeciv, but I haven't installed that game on my system. May be it is a guess by Zenmap. I am running Fedora 16 with gnome 3.2 on my system.

**EDIT 3:** VLC output

```
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: processing request item rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream node Playlist skip 0
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: resyncing on rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream is at 0
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: starting new item
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream'
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: thread (input) created at priority 10 (input/input.c:220)
[0x7f1f88005ec0] main input debug: TIMER input launching for 'rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream' : 15.307 ms - Total 15.307 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 15.307 ms)
[0x2227990] qt4 interface debug: IM: Setting an input
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: thread started
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: using timeshift path '/tmp'
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: `rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream' gives access `rtsp' demux `' path `192.168.1.222:5555/testStream'
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='' path='192.168.1.222:5555/testStream'
[0x7f1f7c002860] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 1 candidate
Opening connection to 192.168.1.222, port 5555...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)


Received 137 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:45:55 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, SET_PARAMETER


Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Accept: application/sdp


Received 641 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:45:55 GMT
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 471

v=0
o=- 1322681211098021 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.222
s=Session streamed by "testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer"
i=test.mpg
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.03.08
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:Session streamed by "testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer"
a=x-qt-text-inf:test.mpg
m=audio 6666 RTP/AVP 14
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.255/7
b=AS:160
a=control:track1
m=video 8888 RTP/AVP 32
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.255/7
b=AS:4500
a=control:track2

[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: RTP subsession 'audio/MPA'
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=6666-6667


Received 182 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:45:55 GMT
Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;destination=192.168.1.255;source=192.168.1.222;port=6666-6667;ttl=7
Session: 06AFB6E5


[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: selecting program id=0
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: RTP subsession 'video/MPV'
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=8888-8889
Session: 06AFB6E5


Received 182 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 5
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:45:55 GMT
Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;destination=192.168.1.255;source=192.168.1.222;port=8888-8889;ttl=7
Session: 06AFB6E5


[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
Sending request: PLAY rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Session: 06AFB6E5
Range: npt=0.000-


Received 268 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete PLAY response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 6
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:45:55 GMT
Range: npt=0.000-
Session: 06AFB6E5
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track1;seq=33348;rtptime=3573241747,url=rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track2;seq=12520;rtptime=2773558772


[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: play start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
[0x7f1f7c002860] main demux debug: using access_demux module "live555"
[0x7f1f7c002860] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 5.536 ms - Total 5.536 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 5.536 ms)
[0x7f1f7c00dca0] main decoder debug: looking for decoder module: 33 candidates
[0x7f1f7c00dca0] main decoder debug: using decoder module "mpeg_audio"
[0x7f1f7c00dca0] main decoder debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.519 ms - Total 0.519 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.519 ms)
[0x7f1f7c00dca0] main decoder debug: thread (decoder) created at priority 5 (input/decoder.c:301)
[0x7f1f7c00dca0] main decoder debug: thread started
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] main decoder debug: looking for decoder module: 33 candidates
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] avcodec decoder debug: libavcodec already initialized
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] avcodec decoder debug: trying to use direct rendering
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] avcodec decoder debug: ffmpeg codec (MPEG-1/2 Video) started
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] main decoder debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] main decoder debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.561 ms - Total 1.561 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.561 ms)
[0x7f1f7c006b90] main packetizer debug: looking for packetizer module: 21 candidates
[0x7f1f7c006b90] main packetizer debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_mpegvideo"
[0x7f1f7c006b90] main packetizer debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.288 ms - Total 0.288 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.288 ms)
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] main decoder debug: thread (decoder) created at priority 0 (input/decoder.c:301)
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] main decoder debug: thread started
[0x7f1f7c008250] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
[0x7f1f7c008250] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/jomit/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f1f7c008250] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib64/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f1f7c008250] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib64/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0x7f1f7c008250] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f1f7c008250] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x7f1f7c008250] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.093 ms - Total 1.093 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.093 ms)
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: `rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream' successfully opened
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux warning: no data received in 10s. Switching to TCP
Sending request: TEARDOWN rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Session: 06AFB6E5


[0x7f1f7c00dca0] main decoder debug: removing module "mpeg_audio"
[0x7f1f7c00dca0] main decoder debug: killing decoder fourcc `mpga', 0 PES in FIFO
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] avcodec decoder debug: ffmpeg codec (MPEG-1/2 Video) stopped
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] main decoder debug: removing module "avcodec"
[0x7f1f7c00e5f0] main decoder debug: killing decoder fourcc `mpgv', 0 PES in FIFO
[0x7f1f7c006b90] main packetizer debug: removing module "packetizer_mpegvideo"
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
Opening connection to 192.168.1.222, port 5555...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)


Received 137 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:46:05 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, SET_PARAMETER


Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Accept: application/sdp


Received 641 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:46:05 GMT
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 471

v=0
o=- 1322681211098021 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.222
s=Session streamed by "testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer"
i=test.mpg
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.03.08
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:Session streamed by "testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer"
a=x-qt-text-inf:test.mpg
m=audio 6666 RTP/AVP 14
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.255/7
b=AS:160
a=control:track1
m=video 8888 RTP/AVP 32
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.255/7
b=AS:4500
a=control:track2

[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: RTP subsession 'audio/MPA'
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1


Received 84 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported Transport
CSeq: 4
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:46:05 GMT


Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=6666-6667


[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: SETUP of'audio/MPA' failed 461 Unsupported Transport
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: RTP subsession 'video/MPV'
Opening connection to 192.168.1.222, port 5555...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=2-3


Received 84 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported Transport
CSeq: 6
Date: Wed, Nov 30 2011 19:46:05 GMT


Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
User-Agent: LibVLC/1.1.12 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.09.02)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=8888-8889


[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: SETUP of'video/MPV' failed RTSP response was truncated. Increase "RTSPClient::responseBufferSize"
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: Nothing to play for rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: TCP rollover failed, aborting
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: EOF reached
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: finished input
Opening connection to 192.168.1.222, port 5555...
[0x7f1f7c002860] main demux debug: removing module "live555"
[0x7f1f88005410] main input debug: thread ended
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: dead input
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
[0x21fa840] main playlist debug: nothing to play
[0x2227990] qt4 interface debug: IM: Deleting the input
```

Everything seems OK, except with the following two errors:

```
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: SETUP of'audio/MPA' failed 461 Unsupported Transport
```

and

```
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: SETUP of'video/MPV' failed RTSP response was truncated. Increase "RTSPClient::responseBufferSize"
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: Nothing to play for rtsp://192.168.1.222:5555/testStream
[0x7f1f7c002860] live555 demux error: TCP rollover failed, aborting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this might have something to do with the use of a non-standard port number, but I may be wrong. The IANA-assigned RTSP port is 554, and 8554 as a secondary IIRC.

It looks like you modifed the live555 code on the server to use 5555 instead. However you don't know if VLC's usage of live555 supports using non-standard RTSP port numbers. I suppose you could look this up in the VLC code.

Things you can try:

- use openRTSP work with the URI
- use a packet sniffer to see what is actually happening on the network i.e. what ports are being used.
- use the standard port and see if that works

These steps will allow you to narrow down where the problem is.

Edit:

From the RTSP comms you can see that VLC is trying to create a unicast session, the server responds with a multicast transport address. VLC then plays the stream, receives no data for 10s and then attempts to start an interleaved RTP over RTSP session to which the server again responds with a multicast address and hence the RTSP server responds with 461.
According to live555:

> testMPEG1or2AudioVideoStreamer reads a MPEG-1 or 2 Program Stream file (named "test.mpg"), extracts from this an audio and a video Elementary Stream, and streams these, using RTP, to the multicast group 239.255.42.42, port 6666/6667 (for the audio stream) and 8888/8889 (for the video stream). This program also has an (optional) built-in RTSP server.

Comment: I first tried default port number 554, but it needs super user permission and I do tried running the program with super user permission. But that doesn't work. That is why I tried changing the port number. Sorry for I haven't mentioned that in the question. I will try other suggestions of yours.

Comment: openRTSP shows `200 OK` status and port check with Zenmap also shows 5555 as an open tcp port. I edited the question to show the outputs. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the question is less that the port is open, but more that VLC might not support opening an RTSP URI on that port, but this is only a guess. One other thing you can try is to use the alternative port 8554 on both client and server if you don't have root access.

Comment: If openRTSP is able to connect, you can see the traffic with say wireshark. Can you see the incoming OPTIONS or DESCRIBE when using VLC? If not, then VLC might not be written to use a non-standard RTSP port. Also, run vlc with the -vvv option will print more info to the messages window or console: check if any warnings/errors show up there.

Comment: Connection seems OK with VLC output, but the errors shown are: `SETUP of'audio/MPA' failed` and `SETUP of'video/MPV' failed`. I appended detailed output to the question.

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish: multicast/unicast? See update of answer

Comment: At last I was able to stream using `live555MediaServer` in `mediaServer` directory. Thanks for your responses. Your last question made me think that it may not be a suitable example and then my googling lead me to that program.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one network interface? Traffic may be going through the wrong interface. You could use Wireshark or other packet sniffer to check that.
Should that be the case, this mail thread may be helpful: 
http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2007-May/006864.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case disabling virtual machine (virtualbox in this case) network adapters worked.